# Grouping in nested sortedlist vb.net

Tags: vb.net, nested, sortedlist

I have a list of objects.

```
    Class Sales
      Public Property CustomerName As String
      Public ItemName As String
      Public Quantity As Double
      ....other details...
    End Class

    Dim records As IList(Of Sales)
```

Any idea how I can group them by CustomerName, followed by ItemName and arrange them into a nested sorted list?

The data type that I want to arrange them to is as follow:-

```
    Dim collection As SortedList(Of String, SortedList(Of String, List(Of Sales)))
```

The key in the outer sortedList would be CustomerName.

The key in the inner sortedList would be ItemName.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: SO is not a place where you ask questions of the form "I want to do X, tell me how". It is a place for questions of the form "I want to do X, this is how I'm trying to do it and this is what happened when I tried, tell me how to fix it". If you haven't tried and failed then you don't have a problem to ask about. Not knowing how to do something is not a reason to post here. It's a reason to research how to do that thing. If you do the research and are unsuccessful, then you've got a reason to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
Dim collection As New SortedList(Of String, SortedList(Of String, List(Of Sales)))( _
    records _
        .GroupBy(Function (r) r.CustomerName) _
        .Select(Function (x) New With { .CustomerName = x.Key, .Items = x.GroupBy(Function (i) i.ItemName) }) _
        .ToDictionary( _
            Function (x) x.CustomerName, _
            Function (x) New SortedList(Of String, List(Of Sales))(x.Items.ToDictionary(Function (y) y.Key, Function (y) y.ToList()))))
```